# Python: how if is handled?

Tags: python, boolean, short-circuiting

Could you please advise how python runs several terms if?

For example:

```
   a = 0
   b = 0
   c = 0

   if a == 0 and b == 1 and c == 0:
   # test fails
```

I guess python internally splits the test into 3 if.
But then, there are 2 possible cases:

- python runs the all 3 if one by one, and one of them is wrong, the test fails
- or python runs if one by one, at the first failed if, the test fails and the others if are not run

How does python run this test internally?

Thank you and regards,
Hugo

Comment: It's short-circuited... ie, the first condition to *not* meet the criteria makes the test fail...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-paramaters-lazily

Comment: To be exact, this is not a property of the `if` clause, but of the `and` / `or` operators.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`and` is a [short-circuit operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

The second argument is evaluated if the first one is `True`.  Similarly, for the subsequent arguments.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't have anything to do with the conditional clause, but the boolean operators `and` and `or`. They are [short-circuit operators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not). If the first value is False, then False is immediately used. Otherwise, the second value is evaluated.

Here's a nice example:

```
>>> def a():
...     print 'a is running!'
...     return True
... 
>>> def b():
...     print 'b is running!'
...     return False
... 
>>> def c():
...     print 'c is running!'
...     return True
... 
>>> if a() and b() and c():
...     print 'hello!'
... 
a is running!
b is running!
```

Because `b` returns `False`, `c` does not end up running because there is no need.

Answer (score 3):

The second.  `and`/`or` are short-circuit operators - if there is no need, the second argument is not evaluated.   See the doc [boolean-operations-and-or-not](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Answer (score 3):

Python uses "lazy evaluation" for `if`:
See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

> "The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned."

Comment: I'm not sure that it's correct to say that python uses lazy evaluation. OP if statement evaluates conditions lazily, yes. The correct term here would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation.

Comment: from wiki: In languages that use lazy evaluation by default (like Haskell), all functions are effectively "short-circuit", and special short-circuit operators are unnecessary.