# Boolean Python Value confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean

I'm new to Python and while trying Python logical statements.I came across this which I'm not able to understand.Can anyone tell me whats happening here in Python 2.7.Whats the difference between 0 and False value in Python.

```
>>> 0 or False
False
>>> False or 0
0
```

Why the interpreter is giving different answers ?

Comment: Notice that both of these values are "falsy"; that is, they both evaluate to `False` in an if statement.

Answer (score 6):

You are being confused by the behaviour of the `or` operator; it returns the first expression that only if it is a *true* value; neither `0` nor `False` is true so the second value is returned:

```
>>> 0 or 'bar'
'bar'
>>> False or 'foo'
'foo'
```

Any value that is not numerical 0, an empty container, `None` or `False` is considered true (custom classes can alter that by implementing a `__bool__` method (python 3), `__nonzero__` (python 2) or `__len__` (length 0 is empty).

The second expression is not even evaluated if the first is `True`:

```
>>> True or 1 / 0
True
```

The `1 / 0` expression would raise a `ZeroDivision` exception, but is not even evaluated by Python.

This is documented in the [boolean operators documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Similarly, `and` returns the first expression if it is `False`, otherwise the second expression is returned.

Comment: "It returns the first expression that is True"
Here in 0 or False 
How False is True ?

Comment: I don't like this answer because the justification "it returns the first expression that is True" doesn't fully explain the behavior. Something like "it goes through the operands and returns the first expression that is True, or the last operand encountered," while less elegant, would better explain the encountered behavior.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: adjusted the wording.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of this behavior is in python's order of [`expression evaluation`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). Python evaluates expressions **from left to right**, and it does it in a [lazy manner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13960657/2183102). This means, that ones interpreter reaches the point, when the value of the expression is `True`, regardless of the rest of the expression, it will follow the branch of workflow, associated with the expression. If none of the expressions is `True`, it will simply return ***the most recent (last one)***. This gives the benefits of saving computational resources. Consider the following code:

```
>>>False or False or True or range(10**8) 
True
>>>
```

Note, that `range(10**8)` is never called in this case, hence, a lot of time is saved.