# Python expression evaluation ("or")

Tags: python, boolean, expression, evaluation

I would like to know how Python evaluates or expressions with integers. Research on the internet has not resulted in satisfactory answers.

**Question 1**

```
5<5 or 10
```

The above results in 10, which I do not understand why.

**Question 2**

How does :

`False or 10`
 Return 10?

And:

How does :

`True or 10` Return True?

**Question 3**

How does:

`5 or 10` Return 5?

**EDIT:**

**Rephrased question:**

`Why does Python return Boolean (True/False) when true and the Value (5 or 10) when false? I understand that it is a language, but is there a reason why it was mad so?`

Comment: Seems that the return of `or` is the *first non False argument* (or `False` if both arguments are `False`)

Comment: What do you mean **how**? Do you mean how is it implemented (in which case, in which distribution? CPython?) or do you really mean **why** (in which case: as opposed to what?)

Comment: Yes, Dmitry explains it correctly. Essentially, you just have to understand that the 'or' operator only cares about whether the objects evaluate to `True` and will return the first one that is, or simply the last one. In your examples of `True or 10` and `5 or 10`, both `True` and `5` evaluate to True (`False` and `0`, for example, would be the counter-opposites in this case as  both would evaluate to False). Also: The `or` operator evaluates the arguments in the order they're set in, but _only_ if preceding ones fail; the second only gets evaluated if the first isn't True, and so on.

Comment: This one is a better duplicate: [Boolean Python Value confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19778268/1025391)

Answer (score 2):

`or` returns the first argument if it is True, otherwise the second argument. In Python, 0 and empty iterables like strings and lists are False, and everything else is True. So `5<5 or 10` evaluates to `False or 10`, so since the first argument is false it returns the second. In the other examples, the first argument is True, so that is returned.

Comment: I think you are correct but the explanation is not as clear as it should be (at least for my taste).

Comment: Could you please check the rephrased question?

Comment: Sorry, your rephrased question doesn't make sense, because Python doesn't do that. As I said, it returns the *first* value, whatever it is, if it's true, otherwise the second value, whatever that is.

Comment: When we execute 0 or False, the output is False. But when we execute False or 0, the output is 0. This is what I meant in the rephrased question.

Comment: @WhiteFlameAB Please have a look at the question linked as duplicate. It is explained in detail there.

Comment: Plus, I've explained it twice already. When the first value is equivalent to false - as it is in both your examples - it returns the second value.