# Boolean expressions in Python

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I have a Python script I'm running that tests for the conjunction of two conditions, one of which is easy to verify and the other hard.  Say I write it as `easy_boole and hard_boole` in Python.  Will the interpreter always check `easy_boole` first and then return `False` if `easy_boole == False`?  Is the interpreter optimized in general to resolve these kinds of statements as quickly as possible?

Comment: Yes. It's shortcircuited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both `and` and `or` are so called short-circuit operators. The evaluation of an `and` expression ends as soon as a value is falsy, the evaluation of an `or` expression ends as soon as a value is truthy.

You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Here is a piece of code with which you can observe this behavior yourself:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

print(False and fib(100)) # prints False immediately
print(True and fib(100)) # takes very, very long
print(fib(100) and False) # takes very, very long
```

So with that in mind, always use `easy_boole and hard_boole`.

Answer (score 3):

Just open up a REPL and try:

```
>>> False and 1 / 0
False

>> True or 1 / 0
True

>>> False or 1 / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

That means that Python indeed evaluates boolean statements lazily.

P.S. It's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-conditions-lazily)

Answer (score 2):

From [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression x and y first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

So as long as `x` is `False`, the expression will be evaluated to `False`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python evaluates if statements lazily. For example, in following code:

```
if f() and g():
    print("GOOD")
else:
    print("BAD")
```

Python interpreter will first check f() statement and if f() is False, it will immediately jump on else statement.