# In Python, what's the point of 'x or False' and 'False and x?

Tags: python, logic, web2py

I'm working with web2py and I've been looking through the source code to get
some better understanding. Multiple times I've seen assignments like

```
# in file appadmin.py
is_gae = request.env.web2py_runtime_gae or False
```

If request.env.web2py_runtime_gae is **true**, then False does not matter. Either way the expression becomes false, if request.env.web2py_runtime_gae is **false**.

And also:

```
# in file appadmin.py
if False and request.tickets_db:
  from gluon.restricted import TicketStorage
```

The second part of the **and** clause is never evaluated, because *False and x* always returns false.

So why would one do something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite like what you are assuming.  Python [evaluates conditions lazily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-conditions-lazily), so if the value is known to satisfy the condition then the evaluation quits.  See this example:

```
>>> None or False
False
>>> True or False
True
>>> 0 or False
False
>>> 'Value' or False
'Value'
```

The second one, as per [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), will simply return `False` on that statement and the rest of the statements will not be evaluated.  This can be a way to unconditionally disable that if statement.

Comment: Python is a fascinating and bizarre language.

Comment: It's a feature called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and is present in many languages, such as JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```
val = x or False
```

Ensures that val is actually 'False' (type 'bool') instead of Falsey values like 0 or "".

The second might be just a temporary disable for that condition?

The best place to investigate might be source control history?