# Unexecuted yield statement blocks function to run?

Tags: python, generator, yield

In the below simplified code, I would like to reuse a loop to do a preparation first and yield the result.

However, the preparation (`bar()`) function is never executed.

Is yield statement changing the flow of the function?

```
def bar(*args,**kwargs):
    print("ENTER bar")
    pass

def foo(prepare=False):
    print("ENTER foo")
    for x in range(1,10):
        if prepare:
            bar(x)
        else:
            yield x


foo(prepare=True)

r = foo(prepare=False)
for x in r:
    pass
```

Comment: Simply containing a `yield` does indeed change the nature of the function. It won't run like a normal function, even if you don't hit a `yield` command.

Comment: @khelwood interesting, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I think the code in the question covers it pretty well. Because the `foo` definition contains a `yield`, it won't run like a normal function even if you call it like one `foo(prepare=True)`. I think this is part of the reason the [new coroutine syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) puts a keyword at the start of the definition, so that the change in nature isn't hidden inside the body of the function.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks, I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `foo` definition contains a yield, it won't run like a normal function even if you call it like one (e.g. `foo(prepare=True)` ).

Running `foo()` with whatever arguments will return a generator object, suitable to be iterated through. The body of the definition won't be run until you try and iterate that generator object.

The [new coroutine syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) puts a keyword at the **start** of the definition, so that the change in nature isn't hidden inside the body of the function.

Comment: Nice, +1, so `bar(x)` is actually stored in a generator too, even though it's not explicitly `yield`ed?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Generators are initially paused; you start them with `.send(None)` and then they stop at each `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that having a `yield` statement changes the function to returning a generator and alters the behavior of the function.

Basically this means that on the call of the `.next` function of the generator the function executes to the `yield` or termination of the function (in which case it raises `StopIteration` exception).

Consequently what you should have done is to ensure that you iterate over it even if the `yield` statement won't be reached. Like:

```
r = foo(prepare=True)
for x in r:
    pass
```

In this case the loop will terminate immediately as no `yield` statement is being reached.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, the actual explanation here is that:

### Python evaluates `if` condition lazily!

And I'll explain:

When you call to

```
foo(prepare=True)
```

just like that, nothing happens, although you might expected that `bar(x)` will be executed 10 times. But what really happen is that 'no-one' demanding the return value of `foo(prepare=True)` call, so the `if` is not evaluated, but it might if you use the return value from `foo`.

In the second call to `foo`, iterating the return value `r`, python has to evaluate the return value,and it does, and I'll show that:

### Case 1

```
r = foo(prepare=True)
for x in r:
    pass
```

The output here is '*ENTER bar*' 9 times. This means that `bar` is executed 9 times.

### Case 2

```
r = foo(prepare=False)
for x in r:
    pass
```

In this case no '*ENTER bar*' is printed, as expected.

---

**To sum everything up**, I'll say that:

- There are some cases where Python perform [**Lazy Evaluation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), [one of them is the `if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-conditions-lazily).
- Not everything is evaluated lazily in Python,

for example:

```
# builds a big list and immediately discards it
sum([x*x for x in xrange(2000000)])
```

**vs.**

```
# only keeps one value at a time in memory
sum(x*x for x in xrange(2000000))
```

About lazy and eager evaluation in python, continue read [here](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/%7Ekmk592/rants/lazy-python/).