# Using 'yield' (i.e. generator) and 'return' together in a Python function

Tags: python, loops, generator

I tried to create a simple Python function where the result is generator or normal output depending on a condition.
But the function did not work. it seems the presence of the keyword 'yield' in the function leads the function to return a generator in all cases.

Below is a simple function that demonstrate what I tried to do.

```py
# Generator function
def square_gen(numbers):
    if len(numbers) > 3:
        for number in numbers:
            yield number**2

    else:
        output= []
        for number in numbers:
            output.append(number**2)
        return output
```

The plan is to call the function in two different ways and get different corresponding outputs:

1. `square_gen([1,2,3])` returns a generator object that I can iterate over (since length of the argument is not greater than 3) .
2. `square_gen([1,2,3,4])` returns `[1,4,9,16]` (since length of the argument is greater than 3).

However, only `1)` works. It returns a generator object that one can iterate over. Surprisingly, `2)` still returns a generator object (I wonder why) but looping over this generator object results in an error.

So basically, I want to know why the non-generator branch of the function still returns a generator object.

Comment: Both the input should return a generator? Because the first case having len=3 should return a list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexecuted yield statement blocks function to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109265/unexecuted-yield-statement-blocks-function-to-run)

Comment: You have already reached the correct conclusions about the behaviour of functions with `yield` in them. What are your clients going to do? Do they already know how long the parameter is that they supply?

Comment: From the docs: [Using yield in a function definition is sufficient to cause that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal function.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement)

Answer (score 4):

You are right in your assumption, having 'yield' anywhere in your method makes a generator, even if it's under an 'if'.

Not that there are many reasons to do it, but if you want to achieve what you asked you can do it like this

```py
def square_gen(numbers):
    if len(numbers) > 3:

        def gen():
            for number in numbers:
                yield number**2
        return gen()

    else:
        output= []
        for number in numbers:
            output.append(number**2)
        return output
```