# Conditional statement on None in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

PFB the program. In that we have a condition block `if  curr > max_v or max_v == None:`. This is giving an error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

However, if I change the condition to `max_v == None or curr > max_v:` it works fine. What is the issue here. Please advice.

```
arr_ele = []

for arr_i in range(6):
    arr_t = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split()]
    arr_ele.append(arr_t)

length = len(arr_ele[0])


max_v = None
curr = 0
for i in range(length-2):
    for j in range(length-2):
        curr = arr_ele[i][j] + arr_ele[i][j+1] + arr_ele[i][j+2] + \
               arr_ele[i+1][j+1] + \
               arr_ele[i+2][j] + arr_ele[i+2][j+1] + arr_ele[i+2][j+2]


        if  curr > max_v or max_v == None:
            max_v = curr

print(max_v)
```

Comment: Write in the opposite order to take advantage of short-circuiting: `if max_v is None or curr > max_v:`.

Comment: The issue is simply that you can't compare an integer to `None`. Unless you know what the minimum value of your list could be, `None` is a perfectly good way to initialize `max_v`; you just have to check for it properly by using `max_v is None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python evaluate if's conditions lazily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-conditions-lazily)

Comment: An `or` statement is evaluated left to right, once one of the condition is evaluated `True`, the interpreter stops checking the rest.

Comment: @DeepSpace That is not logically equivalent. `max_v` should always be updated when `max_v` is currently `None`, but your condition is false in that case.

Comment: Regarding the behaviour of `or`: *"The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned."* Note that the second part is only evaluated if the first part is false. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Comment: @kaya3 Also worth noting that the `and` operator does exactly the opposite.  Once a condition is returned `False`, the rest of the expression is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Python's interpreter is checking if max_v is `None`, if that is `True` then then statement becomes true and the block is executed running `max_v = curr`. if you switch places between statements, the `curr > max_v` is checked.

If the variable `max_v` is `NoneType` when the interpreter reaches the `if` condition then it throws an error because you can't check if an integer is bigger than None.

By putting `curr > max_v` first, that is the statement that is evaluated first, if you put `max_v == None` as the first statement then that is what is evaluated first.

Try to change the `for` loop to give a value to `max_v` or give it a value before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

When Python is processing a logical expression such, it evaluates the expression from left-to-right.
In `curr > max_v or max_v == None`, when the interpreter process `curr > max_v`, if the variable `max_v` has not changed its value (None) since its definition, it would try to compare an `int` and a `NoneType`, and this operation is not defined/allowed.
In the statement `max_v == None or curr > max_v`, if `max_v` is not an integer, the interpreter will never evaluate `curr > max_v`.
A solution would be to use something like:

```
import math
max_v = math.nan # Not a number
...
curr > max_v or max_v == math.nan:
...
```

btw, `max_v == None` [is considered an anti-pattern.](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/comparison_to_none.html)