# Unable to end loop by changing varaible

Tags: python

I am trying to build something simple from a book that I have.  I want it to only accept one of two inputs, either Clockwise or Counterclockwise.  However, the program enters the while loop even while they type Clockwise or Counterclockwise.  Is there a way I can fix this?

```
import turtle

Spin = input("Clockwise or Counterclockwise?")
while Spin != "Clockwise" or Spin != "Counterclockwise":
    print("Please Try Again")
    Spin = {input("Clockwise or Counterclockwise?")}
x = input(str("Put in desired Length:"))
SideLength = int(x)

def drawSideAndTurn(SideLength):
    turtle.forward(SideLength)
    if Spin == "Clockwise":
        turtle.right(90)
    if Spin == "Counterclockwise":
        turtle.left(90)
 y = (input("Number of Sides:"))
 n = int(y)
 x = 1
while x <= n:
    drawSideAndTurn(SideLength)
    drawSideAndTurn(SideLength)
    x += 1
    SideLength += 10
```

Comment: hint: how could `Spin != "Clockwise" or Spin != "Counterclockwise":` ever be false, for any value of `Spin`? (It can't.)

Comment: If `Spin != "Clockwise"` is false, then `Spin != "Counterclockwise"` must be true, and visa-versa.

Comment: I'm new to python so I'm not really sure how to define it so that Spin could be equal to the string input of a user.

Comment: Use `while Spin not in ["Clockwise", "Counterclockwise"]:`

Comment: @RuSXSnIpERXx if `Spin` is `"Clockwise"`, then it's not `"Counterclockwise"`, so the `!= "Counterclockwise"` part of the `if` statement will return `True`, meaning it's never possible for the loop to end. You should do `and` instead of `or`, or use the `not in` example above.

Comment: There are only two options, it is either Clockwise or Counterclockwise. So by making the condition Spin!="Clockwise" or Spin!="Counterclockwise", it will always evaluate to be true. That's like flipping a coin and saying "I win if it's not heads OR it's not tails". That will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Just change “or” to “and”. The input can’t be both be “clockwise” and “counter clockwise” at the same time, that’s why it never exits the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not really sure how to define it so that Spin could be equal to the string input of a user.

The issue isn't in the value in `String`; the issue is in the Boolean condition you're expressing.

Your `while` loop is framed as follows:

```py
while Spin != "Clockwise" or Spin != "Counterclockwise":
    print("Please try again!")
```

Let's walk through the evaluation for arbitrary inputs.

Suppose your user enters `Clockwise`.

1. `Spin != "Clockwise"` will evaluate to `False`
2. `Spin != "Counterclockwise"` is equivalent to `"Clockwise" != "Counterclockwise"`, *which is* `True`
3. `while False or True` is `while True`, so the body of the `while` loop will evaluate.

Suppose instead your user enters `Counterclockwise`.

1. `Spin != "Clockwise"` will evaluate to `True`.
2. `while True or [...]` is `while True`, so the body of the `while` loop will evaluate (Python evaluates Boolean conditions lazily, so it won't even bother testing the part of the expression to the right of the `or`; [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-conditions-lazily)).

If you want to validate the input to ensure it's in one of two values (`Clockwise` or `Counterclockwise`) you need to check something like:

```
while not (Spin == "Clockwise" or Spin == "Counterclockwise"): 
    ...
```

or:

```
while Spin != "Clockwise" and Spin != "Counterclockwise"):
    ...
```

You can express this condition more concisely as:

```
while Spin not in ("Clockwise", "Counterclockwise"):
    ...
```

Better yet, if the set of inputs is known and reasonably fixed, you can write something like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Spin(Enum):
    CLOCKWISE = "clockwise"
    COUNTERCLOCKWISE = "counterclockwise"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value


input_spin = input("Enter direction of spin:")

# Loosely normalize input_spin so that "ClockwiSe    " 
# is treated like a valid input for "clockwise".
while not input_spin.strip().lower() in map(str, Spin):
    ...
```