# problem for a syntax in python, generally the order of statements in the "if" function should not affect the output

Tags: python

hi so i had a doubt in python:

```
def check(message):
    if len(message)==0 or message[0]==message[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(check('else'))
print(check('tree'))
print(check(""))
```

this works.

```
def check(message):
    if message[0]==message[-1] or len(message)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(check('else'))
print(check('tree'))
print(check(""))
```

this doesn't. why?
emphasis on the 'if' function in the check function.

Comment: Nit pick: both *work* perfectly.  But the first protects fromempty input since or shirt circuits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960657/does-python-evaluate-ifs-conditions-lazily

Answer (score 2):

It is because `or` [short-circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): it doesn't evaluate the right argument if there's no need to judging by the value of the left argument.

Eg `if a==0 or f()` will not execute `f()` if a is 0 and thus it makes no difference for the result if `f()` evaluates to True or False.