# how does an operator work in relation to condition and return statement

Tags: python, operators

According to how I understood the operator statement-when given `"statement x" and "statement y"`, assuming that both statements, x and y, are `True`. Given that, the `and` operator represented will check if `statement x` is True, then will move on to `statement y` and will do the same. But once it finished checking the final statement (y) when trying to check (in other words 'refer' to the statements) the statements in the `"statement x" and "statement y"`, we could ONLY check the final statement, IE `statement y`

According to this logic, the first snippet's output, is indeed correct, which confirms my understanding.

```
variable1 = "this is variable 1" 
variable2="this is variable 2" 

def returning(var1,var2):
    return var1 and var2 
print(returning(variable1,variable2))
```

According to my logic, for the second snippet, the loop should never stop because the `and` operator only checks the `y` statement. But, the loop stops, which contradicts my logic. ***Why is there is this contradiction?*** in other words ***What is invalid in my understanding of operators?***

```
x = 3
y = 2
while(x and y):
    print("iteration has been made")
    x=x-1
    user_input = input("Enter something (type 'quit' to exit): ")
    if user_input == "quit":
        break
```

Comment: *"because the `and` operator only checks the `y` statement"* — Well, no, it doesn't. It's the ***`and`*** operator. Its result is truthy if *both* of its operands are truthy. For that it needs to always evaluate `x` and *sometimes* `y`.

Comment: If the first one is falsey the second one won't be checked.

Comment: Your terminology is off. `return` is a *statement*. `def` is a statement, `while` is a statement. `and` is an *operator* which has two *operands*, which are both *expressions*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` become `False` when is equal to 0 (x = x - 1), that's why the loop stops:

```
x = 3
y = 2
while(x and y):
    print(f'Loop x={x}')
    x = x - 1
print(f'Last x={x})
```

Output:

```
Loop x=3  # x and y is True
Loop x=2  # x and y is True
Loop x=1  # x and y is True
Loop x=0  # x and y is False, because x=0
```

Read [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: why do ```x``` become ```False```, why is the fact that ```x==0``` must mean ```False```?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, try `False == 0` is `True`. Same for `True == 1` is `True` but `True == 6` is `False`. It's also `True` for empty sequence. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

In Python `and` and `or` are lazy e.g. are [short circuit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) operators.
Once `x` evaluates to `False`, the statement `x and y` can no longer evaluate to `True`, it doesn't matter what `y` evaluates to.
Also when python evaluates `x` to False once `x == 0`.

See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13960657/20221114)