# Can I cause lazy evaluation of an expression?

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to define an object `master` whose attribute/method `decide` can be called with an expression `ex`, but evaluation of that expression is postponed until some logic in `decide` asks for it (and it may even not do so). So, in code like this:

```
master.decide(ex)
```

it should be possible for `ex` to remain unevaluated if the logic in `decide` says so. In the code, `ex` stands for "arbitrary expression supplied by the client of my library." It can be as simple as `1 + 2` (where I wouldn't really care about lazy evaluation) to as complex as `do_http_request().delete_record_from_database()` (where I certainly *do* care).

Is such a thing possible? I am flexible on the syntax side, so if a solution exists which has to involve extra operators etc. *around* `ex`, I can consider it. But I would like `ex` to remain an expression.

I was thinking about (ab)using short-circuiting operators like `and` and `or`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to make those return something other than a boolean value.

The best I could come up with is wrapping `ex` in a lambda:

```
master.decide(lambda: ex)

def decide(ex):
  if decide_to_do_it():
    result = ex()
    somehow_use(result)
```

Or passing it as a string and using `eval`:

```
master.decide('ex')

def decide(ex):
  if decide_to_do_it():
    result = eval(ex)
    somehow_use(result)
```

(Yes, this one would have scoping issues).

Is there perhaps a magic function, trick, or something else which would allow me to keep `ex` as a plain expression?

Comment: Check this link:
http://stevenloria.com/lazy-evaluated-properties-in-python/ and this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295038/python-lazy-evaluator

Comment: It is unclear what `ex` is in your quest. Is it a previously-coded function to call? A user-passed string to evaluate? In the first ase, you don't need a lambda, you can just call `master.decide(ex)`, python functions being objects you can pass as arguments.

Comment: @DainDwarf Tried to clarify

Comment: Expressions are not objects, therefore they cannot be passed as arguments. Passing a callable (lambda or another function) and calling it inside consuming function is a way to go.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a `coroutine` using `yield` here

```
def decide():
  ex=yield()
  if ex:
     result = ex()
     somehow_use(result)

master=decide()
next(master)
master.send(ex1)
master.send(ex2)
```

Comment: Let's say the client wants an `ex` of the form `insert_record_into_database()`. Can you please explain how this will prevent such an expression from evaluating prematurely?

Comment: @Angew after the first `next` call the program will keep on waiting on `ex=yield()` and will move ahead only when u do a `send` operation.After that the program will again keep waiting till u do another `send`.I guess that is what u want.You can customise it as per ur needs

Comment: From what I understand, this will always evaluate `ex` when the client sends it. That is what I am trying to prevent. I guess there is no way.

Comment: @Angew u can control `ex` from outside and rather send a `single` to `yield` which will run the function.u can control everything here.

Answer (score 3):

You can *pass a callable*, just a function without arguments that is called when the expression needs to be evaluated.

Your lambda is one way to make such a callable, but you could just as easily pass a normal function or an instance method or whatever.

That's is the perfectly normal way to do it.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example that doesn't use a `lambda`. The problem is that @Agnew wants to delay evaluation of an **expression**, not delay the calling of a function. How can you pass an **expression** to anything and prevent it from being evaluated? Isn't it the case that whenever you call a function (decorated or not) the argument is evaluated before the (possibly decorated) function is called? The only way I can see doing it is to wrap the expression in something like `lambda` whose evaluation leaves the expression unevaluated. What options besides `lambda` are there?

Comment: @RussAbbott: yes, you have to wrap the expression into a function. Lambda is one such way, or using a def: statement, possibly as a class method. What you mean when you say "something like" lambda.

Comment: @ RemcoGerlich: Would you mind providing an example of the `def`-method alternative. I don't think you can pass a function *definition* (using `def` rather than `lambda`) or a class *definition* as an argument. Thanks.