# Lazy evaluation of a Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a dictionary that is consistently referred to :

```
def getMyDict():
    myDict = {};
    myDict['1'] = '1'
    return myDict
```

To access a dictionary value I use :

```
getMyDict()['1']
```

How to design dictionary so that the creation of the dictionary is just evaluated once. So that multiple calls to `getMyDict['1']` do not result in multiple calls to `myDict['1'] = '1'`

Coming from Scala this can be accomplished using lazy keyword : [What does a lazy val do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484928/what-does-a-lazy-val-do)

This functionality does not appear to exist in Python as is ?

Closest i found is : [Python lazy evaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295038/python-lazy-evaluator)

The above dictionary example is not real world, but contrived to illustrate the point.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to be lazily evaluated here. The only thing in that dictionary is a string, which does not need evaluation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Which bit should be lazy? Is it something that is expensive to construct so that you only want to do it once if needed or not at all if never really asked for?

Comment: @quamrana please see update, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Once the key has been added, `myDict['1']` does not result in multiple calls to `myDict['1'] = '1'`. Why should it? Moreover, in your example you can add the key at dictionary initialisation: `myDict = {"1": "1"}`;

Comment: No, this does not make it any clearer. Maybe instead of a "contrived" example you should show what you actually want to do.

Comment: @EliKorvigo please see question update.

Comment: Now you've written invalid code. `getMyDict` is a function, so you would need to do `getMyDict()['1']`. But *why* would you do this? If you have a function that returns a dict, assign that return value to a variable.

Comment: Why do you want to create a dictionary anew every time you call `getMyDict`? If you want to encapsulate the dict, you can use a closure. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a modified version (below) of the `run_once` decorator described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29764355/4834).

```
def run_once(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not wrapper.has_run:
             wrapper.has_run = True
             wrapper.cache = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper.cache
    wrapper.has_run = False
    return wrapper

@run_once
def getMyDict():
    myDict = {}
    myDict['1'] = '1'
    print('Run getMyDict')
    return myDict


print(getMyDict()['1'])
print(getMyDict()['1'])
print(getMyDict()['1'])
```

Output:

```
Run getMyDict
1
1
1
```

I am assuming here that your real `getMyDict()` function is a really heavyweight function. Such a function might generate a huge dictionary, taking information from disk or off the internet etc etc.

**Update:**

This technique also works:

One improvement would be to rename this function to describe its *real* purpose:

```
def initMyDict():
    myDict = {}
    myDict['1'] = '1'
    print('Run initMyDict')
    return myDict
```

Now the name of the function implies that it should be run once only.

Now let's write the function you want to call:

```
def getMyDict(myDict=initMyDict()):
    return myDict
```

and let's call it:

```
print(getMyDict()['1'])
print(getMyDict()['1'])
print(getMyDict()['1'])
```

Output:

```
Run initMyDict
1
1
1
```

This technique does have two flaws:

1. The dict is initialised everytime the program runs
2. The call site returns the parameter if you provide one.

Answer (score 2):

I also cannot understand what you mean, but I try to understand. To make it clearer:

```
def Ops():
    print("Ops")

lazy_dict = {}
lazy_dict["Ops"] = Ops()  # not actually evaluate
...
print(lazy_dict["Ops"])   # run here
```

Do you mean something like the above? When bind a value to `dict`'s key, the key just keep a lazy reference to this value instead of the real value.

But it is still confused as is this a behave of `dict` or a behave of value?

For example:

There is a [lib](https://blitiri.com.ar/git/r/pymisc/b/master/t/f=lazy.py.html) which implement a lazy wrapper for functions, if you bind a lazy function to `dict`'s key, it will exactly be a lazy evaluation:

```
import lazy

@lazy
def Ops():
    print("Ops")

lazy_dict = {}
lazy_dict["Ops"] = Ops()  # not actually evaluate
...
print(lazy_dict["Ops"])   # run here
```

Comment: Do you understand the logic of the code of that lib? Or do you have documentation about it? I would like to understand how it works underhood

Answer (score 1):

what i'm comprehending from the question is that you want to make a function to update a dict (and return it as well) but though you've hard-coded `myDict['1'] = '1'`

you are wondering how to put other values in it and not call `myDict['1'] = '1'` again and again.

in my opinion what you can you do is pass the values in the function.

```
def getMydict(key=x, val=y):
    tempDict = {key: val}
    return tempDict
```

`tempDict` has only scope inside the function , so if you want to update a existing dict you can pass the dictionary name as well like.

```
def getMydict(dictname=stuff, key=x, val=y):
    dictname.update({key: val})
    return dictname
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, except my requirement also included being able to have a backing data store. This is what I came up with:

```py
class LazyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, backing_file: Optional[Path] = None, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.backing_file = backing_file
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
        value = super().__getitem__(key)
        if value is None or callable(value):
            value = value()  # Execute the function to get the actual value
            self[key] = value  # Update the dictionary with the generated value
            self.update_backing_file()  # Update the target file if specified
        return value

    def update_backing_file(self) -> None:
        if self.backing_file:
            with self.backing_file.open("w") as f:
                # Dump the dictionary without the callable values
                json.dump(
                    {k: v for k, v in self.items() if not callable(v)}, f, indent=2
                )
```

If you're willing to deviate from the standard dictionary constructor a little you can use something like this, which just takes a dictionary of `Callable`s in addition to optional parameters. The benefit is that you get to specify initialization data yourself and you can modify the `Callable`s later on if needed. It also makes things a little clearer when constructing it:

```py
class LazyDict:
    def __init__(
        self,
        lazy_functions: Optional[Dict[str, Callable[[], Any]]] = None,
        backing_file: Optional[Path] = None,
        initial_data: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.lazy_functions = lazy_functions if lazy_functions is not None else {}
        self.backing_file = backing_file
        self.data: Dict[str, Any] = self.load_initial_data(initial_data)

    def load_initial_data(
        self, initial_data: Optional[Dict[str, Any]]
    ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        if initial_data:
            return initial_data
        elif self.backing_file:
            try:
                with self.backing_file.open("r") as f:
                    return json.load(f)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass  # File doesn't exist, proceed with empty dict
        return {}

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Any:
        try:
            return self.data[key]
        except KeyError:
            if key in self.lazy_functions:
                value = self.lazy_functions[key]()
                self.data[key] = value
                self.update_backing_file()
                return value
            else:
                raise

    def update_backing_file(self) -> None:
        if self.backing_file:
            with self.backing_file.open("w") as f:
                json.dump(self.data, f, indent=2)
```

Note, these both use `pathlib.Path` instead of a string for the backing file.