# python: change a property getter after the fact

Tags: python, performance, properties

Is it possible to change the getter for a python property after it has been created?

```
class A:
    _lookup_str = 'hi'
    @property
    def thing():
        value = some_dictionary[_lookup_str]
        # overwrite self.thing so that it is just value, not a special getter
        return value
```

The idea is that once I've looked it up once, I shouldn't have to look it up again (the dictionary will never change). I could do:

```
class A:
     _lookup_str = 'hi'
     _thing = None
     @property
     def thing():
         if not value:
             value = some_dictionary[_lookup_str]
         return value
```

But even there, I'm testing a condition -- which is more work than if I could remove the getter altogether and replace it with a value.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve ... dictionary lookups are relatively quick, with almost contant time, and using properties assures future requirements are implemented sanely and efficiently ... there is a slight overhead for using properties but its contant ... caching results from heavy/duplicate computations is a whole different story.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky It's not a duplicate. I want a decorator that will produce a self-replacing getter. Tobias wanted a decorator that just does lazy-loading -- the getter doesn't replace itself with the data it calculates / fetches.

Answer (score 7):

Werkzeug has a [`cached_property` decorator](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.cached_property) that does exactly what you want. It just replaces the `__dict__` entry for the function after the first function call with the output of the first call.

Here's the code (from [werkzeug.utils on github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/utils.py) and edited slightly for length):

```
_missing = object()

class cached_property(object):
    """A decorator that converts a function into a lazy property.  The
    function wrapped is called the first time to retrieve the result
    and then that calculated result is used the next time you access
    the value::

        class Foo(object):

            @cached_property
            def foo(self):
                # calculate something important here
                return 42

    The class has to have a `__dict__` in order for this property to
    work.
    """

    # implementation detail: this property is implemented as non-data
    # descriptor.  non-data descriptors are only invoked if there is
    # no entry with the same name in the instance's __dict__.
    # this allows us to completely get rid of the access function call
    # overhead.  If one choses to invoke __get__ by hand the property
    # will still work as expected because the lookup logic is replicated
    # in __get__ for manual invocation.

    def __init__(self, func, name=None, doc=None):
        self.__name__ = name or func.__name__
        self.__module__ = func.__module__
        self.__doc__ = doc or func.__doc__
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        value = obj.__dict__.get(self.__name__, _missing)
        if value is _missing:
            value = self.func(obj)
            obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = value
        return value
```

(btw - is it better to post code or a link to code for something like this?)

If you'd like to learn more about why this works, check out the [Python docs on descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).  The code above creates a non-data descriptor (unlike `@property`) which allows it to be overwritten.

Comment: Coping code here is preferred; from [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer): "A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there . Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Note that you probably need to do something like `_missing = object()` before this code will work.

Comment: @Dougal good point, `_missing` in Werkzeug is just a subclass of object with a special `__repr__` and `__reduce__`. I just put in what you said...definitely easier to read when using that as a sentinel value.

Comment: there is [a simpler solution for old-style classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12085074/4279)

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as indicated by Jeff Tratner, is to overwrite the property object found in the `__dict__` of the python object. Werkzeug's cached_property seems overcomplicated to me. The following (much simpler) code works for me:

```
def cached_property(f):
    @property
    def g(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'trace'
        value = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__[f.__name__] = value
        return value
    return g

class A:
    @cached_property
    def thing(self):
        return 5

a = A()
print a.thing
print a.thing
print a.thing
print a.thing

# 'trace' is only shown once -- the first time a.thing is accessed.
```

Comment: When I tried to run your code, it didn't work in 2.7 or 3.2; it shows 'trace' every time. Also, the way you have it set up, you have to explicitly define a setter for the property to overwrite it.

Comment: Are you sure you ran it in python 2.7? In Python 2.7.2 I get `trace` once and `5` four times. I haven't tested it in 3.2 but nehz seems to agree with you it won't work with Python 3.

Comment: the issue is whether you use old-style vs. new-style classes (so if you add a `class B(object):` that is the same in every other way to `A`, you'll get the trace over and over again).  The issue is that `property` creates a data descriptor, so you can't override it without the setter and it ignores the `__dict__` lookup.  If you define it with just a `__get__` method, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended but it works for old-style classes:

```
>>> class A:
...   @property
...   def thing(self):
...       print 'thing'
...       self.thing = 42
...       return self.thing
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.thing
thing
42
>>> a.thing
42
>>> a.thing
42
```

It doesn't work for new-style classes (subclasses of type, object) so it won't work on Python 3 where all classes are new-style. Use [@Jeff Tratner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12084534/4279) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by J.F. Sebastian and Isaac Sutherland do not work with new style classes. 
It will produce the result Jeff Tratner mentions; printing out trace on every access.

For new style classes, you will need to override `__getattribute__`

Simple fix:

```
def cached_property(f):
    @property
    def g(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'trace'
        value = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__[f.__name__] = value

        return value
    return g

def cached_class(c):
    def d(self, name):
        getattr = object.__getattribute__
        if (name in getattr(self, '__dict__')):
            return getattr(self, '__dict__')[name]
        return getattr(self, name)

    c.__getattribute__ = d
    return c

@cached_class
class A(object):
    @cached_property
    def thing(self):
        return 5

a = A()
print a.thing
print a.thing
print a.thing
print a.thing
```