# expression evaluation in if elif statements

Tags: python

Given code like this:

```
if f(a) == 1:
    # do sth A
elif f(a) == 2:
    # do sth B
elif f(a) == 3:
    # do sth C
else:
    # do sth D
```

Does the expression `f(a)` get executed/evaluated only once? Or does it get executed/evaluated for every case of `if` or `elif`? In addition, do compound statements make any difference: e.g.

```
if f(a) == 1:
    # do sth A
elif f(a) == 2 and a > 0:
    # do sth B
elif f(a) == 3 and a < 0:
    # do sth C
else:
    # do sth D
```

In this case, how does `f(a)` get evaluated? Once for all or individually for each case?

Comment: f(a) will keep getting re-evaluated because it's not easy to prove it will or won't produce the same value every call.

Comment: even stronger than that, it is not required to produce the same value every call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test it out:

```
In [7]: %paste
def f(a):
    print(a)

a = 4

if f(a) == 1:
    pass
elif f(a) == 2:
    pass
elif f(a) == 3:
    pass
else:
    pass

## -- End pasted text --
4
4
4
```

`f(a)` will keep on getting evaluated because there's no guarantee that `f(a)` will return the same result each time, so Python won't assume that it will. You can cache it with `result = f(a)` and use `result` in place of `f(a)`.

If any of those `if` blocks happens to be `True`, the ones after it will not be tested.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that an `if` statement with several `elif` statements can be expressed as a nested set of `if` and `else` blocks. That is, `elif` is just "syntactic sugar" for `else: if` (but it saves a level of indentation, so it's very handy!). The following block is equivalent to the first `if` and `elif` of your code:

```
if f(a) == 1:
    pass
else:
    if f(a) == 2:
        pass
```

With this in mind, the number of times the expression gets evaluated depends on what its result is, since you'll only go into the `else` parts if the previous tests were failed. If the first call to `f(a)` returns `1`, then none of the other calls will be made. However, if all the tests fail (except perhaps the last one), they'll all need to be evaluated.

Similarly, within a logical expression using `and` and `or`, Python will short-circuit and not evaluate any parts of the expression that are not needed to determine the final value.

```
if f(a) == 1: # f(a) always gets evaluated here
     pass
elif f(a) == 2: # f(a) gets called a second time here if the "if" was failed
     pass
elif a<1 and f(a): # f(a) runs again only if both previous tests failed and a<1
     pass
```

So in summary, you can't tell how many times the function `f(a)` will run unless you know it's results ahead of time. If `f(a)` is not idempotent (that is, if it has side effects), you probably don't want to structure your code that way!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it gets executed Every time it is called. ( I use python 2.7, wouldn't think it has changed in 3.x)

You could put a print statement in to verify.

That's why it could be better to only call it once and get the return value for your conditionals

You could [cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values) the functions return value? But it could be more straight forward just to call function 1x:

```
f_value = f(a)
if f_value == 1:
    # do sth A
elif f_value == 2:
    # do sth B
elif f_value == 3:
    # do sth C
else:
    # do sth D
```