# Python function loop

Tags: python

I am picking up Python and so far I love it, but just 3 days back I came across something that I could not understand. what happens is that I made a function, It takes input from the user and runs the result through the if elif conditions. But when I run the program it is taking multiple inputs though I just asked for one.

I made two programs but they both take multiple inputs. I am including just one.

Here is the code

```
def Power():
        var1=int;
        var2=int;
        var3=float;
        var1=input("Please Enter Value for A: ");
        var2=input("Please Enter Value for B: ");
        var3=int(var1)/int(var2);
        return var3;


    if (float(Power())>4):
        print("The Result is: "+ str(Power()));
    elif(float(Power())<4):
        print(Power());
```

and here is the output I am getting.

[image: Python Program output]

Please help me out and guide me how to be a good developer of Python.

Thank you

Comment: Please format your code as you made it. Intend and outend your code good. I'm sorry if I've broke your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [expression evaluation in if elif statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247212/expression-evaluation-in-if-elif-statements)

Comment: You should also have a look at some Python tutorial, like [the official one](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/). Your code looks like some other language at the moment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function multiple times, so it will repeat asking for inputs whenever it's called via `Power()`

Because your function returns a value you should assign it to a variable and use that local variable in your if statements, e.g.

```
def Power():
    var1=int
    var2=int
    var3=float
    var1=input("Please Enter Value for A: ")
    var2=input("Please Enter Value for B: ")
    var3=int(var1)/int(var2)
    return var3

myLocalVariable = float(Power())

if (myLocalVariable>4):
    print("The Result is: "+ str(myLocalVariable))
elif(myLocalVariable<4):
    print(myLocalVariable)
```

Comment: As well, you don't need `;` at the end of lines in python

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets do this in a "Pythonic" way:

```
def power(a: int, b: int) -> float:
    """
    Explain whatever the functions does
    :param a: Explain a
    :param b: Explain b
    :return: explain what it returns
    """
    return float(a / b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        user_input1 = int(input("Please Enter Value for A: "))
        user_input2 = int(input("Please Enter Value for B: "))

        result = power(user_input1, user_input2)
        print("The Result is: %s" % result if result > 4 else result)
    except ValueError:
        print("Value entered is not an integer.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

> Note: I assumed you used python3

A good way to start writing python code is reading the `PEP`s, start with [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also I suggest you to get [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/specials/pycharm/pycharm.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwnfLVBRCxARIsAPvl82Fmdp5fUMqkFLb5blQuHVgUZIfloUFC4HJcZpaW3NjAf-9gCNUZsysaApw4EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=CLu9rIWnktoCFeuiUQodsIgO5w) it will help you a lot with coding styles and python standards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a few more changes to the code that @Austin A has suggested.

To start of with, here are a few pointers that you may consider while enjoying Python :

1. Python is **;** free!. Just use appropriate indentation and you're good to go. Refer this for more : [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/indentation.html)
2. You can declare a variable anytime you need it. There's no compulsion of it's prior declaration. Just assign it a value, prior to it's usage, and it's ready for use.
3. Regardless of the language, only if the function(which returns some value) has to operate on different values of arguments, then only you should call it more than once, as per the requirement.

   - However, if you wish to call the function, for a single set of argument values, then you should just call it once and store it's value in a variable. Then use the variable as much as you need. This is an efficient way to use functions.

Now proceeding on with the code:

```
def Power():
    #Earlier declarations become meaningless, if you're going to redeclare the variable  
    #In Python, the variables change their data type as per their values 
    var1=input("Please Enter Value for A: ")
    var2=input("Please Enter Value for B: ")
    #This float conversion ,can splendidly take care of your type cast worries
    var3=float(var1)/var2
    return var3

#Once, the 'float' conversion is done, then you don't have to 
#explicitly mention it again and again for assignments or comparison. 
#Leave that task for Python 
myLocalVariable=Power()

if myLocalVariable>4:
    print("The Result is: "+ str(myLocalVariable))
elif myLocalVariable<4:
    print(myLocalVariable)
```

I think, this may suit your needs! For any other worries on this answer, drop your comments below.

Have fun with Python!

Comment: Function should not start with capital, variables should not use camel case but underscore_case... `def Power()` should be `def power()` and `myLocalVariable` should be `my_local_variable`. No offense but too much talk to copy @Austin A answer.

Comment: None taken @epinal. The correction for the function name is totally right. However, I believe that use of camelcase variable names is also fine. In my knowledge, I've seen it in various codes. So, I believe underscore or camelcase, both work just fine.

Comment: Check this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions. 
`
Function and variable names

Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.
`

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it and it works. But can you tell me what was my mistake and why did you use the variable "myLocalvariable"?

Comment: I believe that first you wish to take user input and then perform comparison. However, in your code, you've called your function 'Power()', first in your comparison statement & then in 'print()'. I believe that you did so, in order to have the same return value from 'Power()' in both statements. But this lead to multiple input requests, since you've the 'input()' in your 'Power()' & the no. of times 'Power()' is called, the same no. of times you'll have those 'input()' called too. Hence, to achieve the aim, I just called 'Power()' once and stored it's return value in the 'myLocalVariable'

Comment: Understood & thanks.