# Coin change with limited coins complexity

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

If there is an unlimited number of every coin then the complexity is `O(n*m)` where is `n` is the total change and `m` is the number of coin types. Now when the coins for every type are limited then we have to take into account the remaining coins. I managed to make it work with a complexity of `O(n*m2)` using another for of size `n` so I can track the remaining coins for each type. Is there a way-trick to make the complexity better? EDIT : The problem is to compute the least ammount of coins required to make the exact given change and the number of times that we used each coin type

Comment: Why do you need another for loop?

Comment: For the limited case, we have to use an array dp[total_change][total_supply] and change its value accordingly so that we have a different condition in its iteration. At least that's how I used it. My condition was if
dp[j - coin_type[i]][i] >0 where j>0, j<=n and i>0, i<m @SumeetSingh

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Comment: So using my method, time complexity would remain O(n*m).

Comment: The problem is that in a dynamic programming implementation you are computing the result indirectly, so I can't possibly know when to reduce the current quantity. @SumeetSingh

Comment: Can you clarify: is the question to count the number of ways of making change for n with a given finite set of coins?

Comment: The question is to compute the least ammount of coins required to make the exact given change and the number of times that we used each coin.
@PaulHankin

Comment: @Mitsos, this is essential information ("least amount") that is missing from your question: you should edit it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for an extra loop. You need to:

- recurse with a depth of at most *m* (number of coins) levels, dealing with one specific coin per recursion level.
- Loop at most *n* times at each recursion level in order to decide how many you will take of a given coin.

Here is how the code would look in Python 3:

```py
def getChange(coins, amount, coinIndex = 0):
    if amount == 0:
        return [] # success
    if coinIndex >= len(coins):
        return None # failure
    coin = coins[coinIndex]
    coinIndex += 1
    # Start by taking as many as possible from this coin
    canTake = min(amount // coin["value"], coin["count"])
    # Reduce the number taken from this coin until success
    for count in range(canTake, -1, -1): # count will go down to zero
        # Recurse to decide how many to take from the next coins
        change = getChange(coins, amount - coin["value"] * count, coinIndex)
        if change != None: # We had success
            if count: # Register this number for this coin:
                return change + [{ "value": coin["value"], "count": count }]
            return change


# Example data and call:
coins = [
    { "value": 20, "count":  2 },   
    { "value": 10, "count":  2 },
    { "value":  5, "count":  3 },
    { "value":  2, "count":  2 },
    { "value":  1, "count": 10 }
]

result = getChange(coins, 84)
print(result)
```

Output for the given example:

```
[
    {'value': 1, 'count': 5},
    {'value': 2, 'count': 2},
    {'value': 5, 'count': 3},
    {'value': 10, 'count': 2},
    {'value': 20, 'count': 2}
]
```

#### Minimising the number of coins used

As stated in comments, the above algorithm returns the first solution it finds. If there is a requirement that the number of individual coins must be minimised when there are multiple solutions, then you cannot `return` halfway a loop, but must retain the "best" solution found so far.

Here is the modified code to achieve that:

```
def getchange(coins, amount):
    minCount = None

    def recurse(amount, coinIndex, coinCount):
        nonlocal minCount
        if amount == 0:
            if minCount == None or coinCount < minCount:
                minCount = coinCount
                return [] # success
            return None # not optimal
        if coinIndex >= len(coins):
            return None # failure
        bestChange = None
        coin = coins[coinIndex]
        # Start by taking as many as possible from this coin
        cantake = min(amount // coin["value"], coin["count"])
        # Reduce the number taken from this coin until 0
        for count in range(cantake, -1, -1):
            # Recurse, taking out this coin as a possible choice
            change = recurse(amount - coin["value"] * count, coinIndex + 1, 
                                                             coinCount + count)
            # Do we have a solution that is better than the best so far?
            if change != None: 
                if count: # Does it involve this coin?
                    change.append({ "value": coin["value"], "count": count })
                bestChange = change # register this as the best so far
        return bestChange

    return recurse(amount, 0, 0)

coins = [{ "value": 10, "count":  2 },
         { "value":  8, "count":  2 },
         { "value":  3, "count": 10 }]

result = getchange(coins, 26)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
    {'value': 8, 'count': 2},
    {'value': 10, 'count': 1}
]
```

Comment: With coin values of 10, 8 and 3 and a target of 26, this returns 2 3's and 2 10's instead of the more optimal 1 10 and 2 8's.

Comment: @Dukeling, true. There was no mention of what was considered optimal in the OP's question, but just in case, I added a variant of the code that will return a solution that minimises the number of individual coins used.

Comment: Both of these look like they would take exponential time in the worst case, which is significantly slower than the dynamic programming approach. (Recursion depth of m with a loop of n iterations is O(n^m), not O(mn))

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of an O(nm) solution in Python.

If one defines `C(c, k) = 1 + x^c + x^(2c) + ... + x^(kc)`, then the program calculates the first `n+1` coefficients of the polynomial `product(C(c[i], k[i]), i = 1...ncoins)`. The `j`'th coefficient of this polynomial is the number of ways of making change for `j`.

When all the `k`s are unlimited, this polynomial product is easy to calculate (see, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743780/1400793). When limited, one needs to be able to calculate running sums of `k` terms efficiently, which is done in the program using the `rs` array.

```
# cs is a list of pairs (c, k) where there's k
# coins of value c.
def limited_coins(cs, n):
    r = [1] + [0] * n
    for c, k in cs:
        # rs[i] will contain the sum r[i] + r[i-c] + r[i-2c] + ...
        rs = r[:]
        for i in xrange(c, n+1):
            rs[i] += rs[i-c]
            # This line effectively performs:
            # r'[i] = sum(r[i-j*c] for j=0...k)
            # but using rs[] so that the computation is O(1)
            # and in place.
            r[i] += rs[i-c] - (0 if i<c*(k+1) else rs[i-c*(k+1)])
    return r[n]

for n in xrange(50):
    print n, limited_coins([(1, 3), (2, 2), (5, 3), (10, 2)], n)
```

Comment: As noted in the comments, the question is to compute the least number of coins required, not the total number of ways to get there.