# How can I count distinct combinations in coin change?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

```
long long num(long long p)
{
   if(p<0)
      return 0;
   if(p==0)
      return 1;
   if(t[p]!=0)
      return t[p];
   t[p]=num(p-1)+num(p-2)+num(p-5)+num(p-10)+num(p-20)+num(p-50)+num(p-100);
   return t[p];
}
```

I use this method `num` to count number of possible ways of coin change problem.The problem is this approach counts `1,1,2` and `1,2,1` as different which should be taken as 1 .How to do that?
Cant find any good solution anywhere.

Comment: This seems something for Math SO

Comment: You should probably try [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You just need to remember `lastUsedCoinIndex` and consider only coin indexes greater or equal. See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257659/python-coin-change-dynamic-programming/46261706#46261706

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++ implementation of the number of distinct coin combos.

```
int combo(int d[], int r, int R)
{
    if (R == 0)
        return 1;
    if (R < 0)
        return 0;

    int tot = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
        tot += combo(d, r, R - d[i]);

    return tot;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this is exactly same as my code except you used a for loop .This will count 1,1,2 and 1,2,1 as two different possibilities what i want is them to be counted as 1.