# Given a list of tuple coordinates, find the nearest coord to a specified coord

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to do this? My current implementation is very messy:

```
def distanceTo(self, start, end):
    """Distance from cell A to cell B."""
    startx, starty = start
    endx, endy =  end
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(math.fabs(endx - startx), 2)
                     + math.pow(math.fabs(endy - starty), 2))


def findNearestBuildings(self, myCoords, buildingGroup):
    """Returns a list of buildings specified, in ascending order of distance"""
    if len(buildingGroup.sprites()) == 0:
        return None
    buildings = []
    distances = []
    for building in buildingGroup.sprites():
        distance = self.distanceTo(myCoords, building.coords)
        for i in range(len(buildings)):
            if distances[i] < distance:
                if i == len(buildings):
                    buildings.append(building)
                    distances.append(distance)
            elif distances[i] >= distance:
                buildings.insert(i, building)
                distances.insert(i, distance)
        if len(buildings) == 0:
            buildings.append(building)
            distances.append(distance)
    return buildings
```

What would be a more efficient way to do this? I am using PyGame but this should be a fairly universally applicable question. All coordinates are integer values.

Comment: I think [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is better place for your question.

Comment: And I guess there could happen to be 2 coords at the same distance, right?

Comment: Sorry @Michal I didn't know about that. Will post there in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother taking the square root! It is slo-o-o-o-w on a computer. If one building is nearer than another, the square of the distance between them will also be less than the squares of the distances to other buildings.

What I mean is, if the nearest building is 10 metres away and the next two nearest building are 11 metres and 12 metres away, you can just as easily compare 100 (10^2) and say it is less than 121 (11^2) and 144 (12^2) - this will always be true since

```
if a < b then a^2 < b^2  (for all positive a and b)
```

Essentially, I mean to do this

```
return (endx - startx)*(endx-startx) + (endy - starty)*(endy - starty)
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying here, but I'm not sure how I'd implement it. Could you possibly write up an example for me?

Comment: Remove the math.sqrt, and math.fabs.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use this distance at some later point for some other purpose than finding the nearest, you will need to do the sqrt(), but only for the nearest one, not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Find distances to all buildings (N).
Sort distances (Nln(N)).

That's the fastest way.

Comment: It said find nearest buildings.  He seems to want an ascending list.

Answer (score 2):

a few common tips you can apply:

- if your list evolves slowly, you can cache the `distance` function (e.g. with a decorator or manually with a dict), see [Here for examples and links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values)
- your `distance` function could might be way quicker using another norm (`max.fabs(x-x0),math.fabs(y-y0))`) : this would prevent the slow sqrt
- your squaring values, no need to use `fabs` on them
- you can use the sorted primitive to make your function easy to read (unless I misunderstood what it's doing)

Example:

```
def findNearestBuildings(self, myCoords, buildingGroup):
      return sorted(buildingGroup.sprites(),key= lambda x:self.distance(x,myCoords))
```