# Using Python, how can I wrap a class so that later, a replacement stub can reproduce it if stimulated the same way?

Tags: python, facebook, unit-testing

I am trying to write some unit tests on code that uses the Facebook API.  In order to make the unit tests a bit faster and sturdier (since the tokens expire) I thought I could mock out the Python facebook-sdk GraphAPI object.  That way, I can record the API result once then just keep it cached, so future unit tests need not pull it again.

However, the best meta-y Python eludes me, and I was looking for preexisting solutions or a good basis upon which to build.  What approach will work?

Comment: Are you looking for preexisting solutions specifically for facebook's API? Or just for a [mocking framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/)?

Comment: Either - a Facebook API one would be great, and I'm sure I'm not the only one in this situation.  `mock` wouldn't record the facebook api itself, i'd have to somehow capture all the returns myself and then feed them into `mock`.  That might be acceptable though.

Comment: If you already have the API functions in a computer-readable format, it shouldn't be too hard. You can also look into modifying a [caching decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values) to use a disk-based storage