# Geopy too slow - timeout all the time

Tags: python, error-handling, geolocation, timeout, geopy

I am using geopy to get latitude - longitude pairs for city names.
For single queries, this works fine. What I try to do now is iterating through
a big list of city names (46.000) and getting geocodes for each city. Afterwards, I run them through a check loop which sorts the city (if it is in the US) in the correct state. My problem is, that I get "GeocoderTimedOut('Service timed out')"
all the time, everything is pretty slow and I'm not sure if that is my fault or just geopys nature.
Here is the responsible code snippet:

```
for tweetcount in range(number_of_tweets):

#Get the city name from the tweet
city = data_dict[0]['tweetList'][tweetcount]['user']['location']

#Sort out useless tweets
if(len(city)>3 and not(city is None)): 

    # THE RESPONSIBLE LINE, here the error occurs
    location = geolocator.geocode(city);

    # Here the sorting into the state takes place
    if location is not None:
        for statecount in range(len(data)):
            if point_in_poly(location.longitude, location.latitude, data[statecount]['geometry']):

                state_tweets[statecount] += 1;
                break;
```

Somehow, this one line throws timeouts at every 2./3. call. City has the form 
of "Manchester", "New York, New York" or something similar.
I already had try - except blocks around everything, but that doesn't really change anything about the problem, so I removed them for now... Any ideas would be great!

Comment: unrelated but `if location is not  None:` would be a lot more readable

Comment: did you try to increase the timeout? geolocator.geocode(city, timeout=10);

Comment: Even with timeout = 10, I still get the error.
If I run the code 5 times, I usually get the error 3-4 time, the other 1-2 times it works just fine, though it takes a bit longer than it should.

Answer (score 3):

You will be at the mercy of whatever geolocator service you are using. `geopy` is just a wrapper around different web-services and hence may fail if the server is busy. I would create a wrapper around the `geolocator.geocode` call, something like this:

```
def geocode(city, recursion=0):
    try:
        return geolocator.geocode(city)
    except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
        if recursion > 10:      # max recursions
            raise e

        time.sleep(1) # wait a bit
        # try again
        return geocode(city, recursion=recursion + 1)
```

This will try again 10 times, after a delay of 1 second. Adjust these numbers to your liking.

If you repeatably ask for the same city, you should consider wrapping it in some kind of memoizing e.g. [this decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values).
Since you have not posted a runnable code, I have not been able to test this.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your line :

```
location = geolocator.geocode(city);
```

to

```
location = geolocator.geocode(city,timeout=None);
```