# fibonacci sequence using recursion with negative numbers python

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a program that finds the fibonacci sequence of any given number using the formula:
**F<sub>-n</sub> = (-1)<sup>n+1</sup>F<sub>n</sub>**

I have written the code for the positive side, which works, but I am getting nonstop recursion when I enter a negative number.

```
def fib(n):
    if n > -1:
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif n == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    if n <= -1:
        return ((-1)**(n+1)) + fib(n)


num = eval(input("enter a number: "))
print("The value of the fibonacci series for the number", num, "is: ", fib(num))
```

Comment: Negative Fibonacci numbers don't exist.

Comment: Sorry, gents, but the definition does exist by logical extension.  f(n-2) = f(n) - f(n-1).  You continue to work away from 0.

Comment: Eval in a user input... omgomgomgomgomgomgomgomg Run! **:-D** @aqueduct, check http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: For those unenlightened about the bidrectional sequence, [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) the description.

Comment: as @BorrajaX wrote: don't use `eval` if you dont have to, don't **ever** use `eval(input())`. You want `int(input())`

Comment: Yep, the Fibonacci sequence can be extended to [negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Extension_to_negative_integers). It can even be extended to all real numbers! But there isn't a canonical extension in that case.

Comment: If you are calculating fibonacci with recursion, you might want to learn about [lru cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values). Makes the whole thing much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

For the negative side, your last clause, you have to call **fib(-n)**, the absolute value of **n**.

```
if n <= -1:
    return ((-1)**(n+1)) + fib(-n)   # Note the negation; abs(n) would also work.
```

If you insist on calculating it directly, you need to maintain the relation:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

To solve this for the *least* number:

```
f(n-2) = f(n) - f(n-1)
```

... and then normalize for the current negative value: let j = n-2:

```
f(j) = f(j+2) - f(j+1)
```

Can you handle the variations from there?

Answer (score 0):

The `if n <= -1:` part of your implementation is not correct, if you look at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#List_of_Fibonacci_numbers), it shows the negative generalization as a multiplication, not an addition:

```
return((-1)**n+1) * f(-n))
```

I've taken into account the correction from @prune, this should work in python. I've tested it in R and the output matches the sequence given in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement `((-1)**(n+1)) + fib(n)` is not correct as per the equation mentioned by you

> F(-n) = ((-1)^n+1)*F(n)

The computer can't differentiate between '-' sign and a number, it evaluates a negative number(eg.-3) as a whole literal(number). In the equation, we are finding the value for F(n) but in your return statement, you are finding the solution for F(-n).

For Instance, if you take the n=-3,

F(-3) = ((-1)^(-3+1))*F(-3) =>(-1)*F(-3)  //This is according to your return statement, the system can't evaluate F(-3) in RHS.

The correct form will be,
F(-3) = ((-1)^(-3+1))*F(-(-3)) =>(-1)*F(3) //So, you have to negate the value for F(-3) in RHS before recursion.

So the corrected statement is,`((-1)**(n+1)) + fib(-n)`

Note: RHS(Right Hand Side), Negate(Making a number negative by multiplying it with -1)

Answer (score 0):

The following Fibonacci code is using iteration. the argument n is any integer (positive or negative). It produces exactly the same result as
**F<sub>-n</sub> = (-1)<sup>n+1</sup>F<sub>n</sub>**

```
def fibo(n):
    if n>=0:
       idx = range(n+1)
       x = [0,1]
       for k in idx[2:]:
           x.append(x[k-1] + x[k-2]) 
       return x[n]
    else:
       n=-(n-1)
       idx = range(n+1)
       x = [1,0]
       for k in idx[2:]:
           x.append(x[k-2] - x[k-1]) 
       x.reverse()
    return x[0]

for i in range(-13,14):
   print(i,fibo(i))
```

It would produce

```
-13 233
-12 -144
-11 89
-10 -55
-9 34
-8 -21
-7 13
-6 -8
-5 5
-4 -3
-3 2
-2 -1
-1 1
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 5
6 8
7 13
8 21
9 34
10 55
11 89
12 144
13 233
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for calculating an element in the Fibonacci sequence with negative numbers:

```
def f(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        if n < 0:
            return ((-1)**(-n+1)) * f(-n)
        return f(n-1)+f(n-2)
```