# What difficulties might arise from using mutable arguments to an `lru_cache` decorated function?

Tags: python, caching, python-decorators

In the comment: [Is there a decorator to simply cache function return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values/9674327?noredirect=1#comment76137301_9674327)

@gerrit points out a problem with using mutable, but hashable, objects to to a function with the `functools.lru_cache` decorator:

> If I pass a hashable, mutable argument, and change the value of the
>   object after the first call of the function, the second call will
>   return the changed, not the original, object. That is almost certainly
>   not what the user wants.

From my understanding, **assuming** the `__hash__()` function of the mutable objects is manually defined to hash the member variables (and not just using the object's `id()` that is the default for custom objects), changing the argument object will change the hash, hence, a second call should to the `lru_cache` decorated function should not utilize the cache.

If the `__hash__()` function is defined correctly for the mutable argument(s), is there any unattended behavior that can arise from using mutable arguments to `lru_cache` decorated functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment was wrong/misleading and does not relate to `lru_cache`, but to any attempt to create a caching function that works more generically.

I was facing a need for a caching function that works for function that input and output `NumPy` arrays, which are mutable and not hashable.  Because `NumPy` arrays are not hashable, I could not use `functools.lru_cache`.  I ended up wroting something like this:

```
def mutable_cache(maxsize=10):
    """In-memory cache like functools.lru_cache but for any object

    This is a re-implementation of functools.lru_cache.  Unlike
    functools.lru_cache, it works for any objects, mutable or not.
    Therefore, it returns a copy and it is wrong if the mutable
    object has changed!  Use with caution!

    If you call the *resulting* function with a keyword argument
    'CLEAR_CACHE', the cache will be cleared.  Otherwise, cache is rotated
    when more than `maxsize` elements exist in the cache.  Additionally,
    if you call the resulting function with NO_CACHE=True, it doesn't
    cache at all.  Be careful with functions returning large objects.
    Everything is kept in RAM!

    Args:
        maxsize (int): Maximum number of return values to be remembered.

    Returns:
        New function that has caching implemented.
    """

    sentinel = object()
    make_key = functools._make_key

    def decorating_function(user_function):
        cache = {}
        cache_get = cache.get
        keylist = []  # don't make it too long

        def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
            if kwds.get("CLEAR_CACHE"):
                del kwds["CLEAR_CACHE"]
                cache.clear()
                keylist.clear()
            if kwds.get("NO_CACHE"):
                del kwds["NO_CACHE"]
                return user_function(*args, **kwds)
            elif "NO_CACHE" in kwds:
                del kwds["NO_CACHE"]
            key = str(args) + str(kwds)
            result = cache_get(key, sentinel)
            if result is not sentinel:
                # make sure we return a copy of the result; when a = f();
                # b = f(), users should reasonably expect that a is not b.
                return copy.copy(result)
            result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
            cache[key] = result
            keylist.append(key)
            if len(keylist) > maxsize:
                try:
                    del cache[keylist[0]]
                    del keylist[0]
                except KeyError:
                    pass
            return result

        return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper, user_function)

    return decorating_function
```

In my first version, I had omitted the `copy.copy()` function (which should really be `copy.deepcopy()`), which led to bugs if I changed the resulting value and then recalled the cached-function.  After I added the `copy.copy()` functionality, I realised that I was hogging memory for some cases, primarily because my function counts objects, not total memory usage, which is non-trivial to do in general in Python (although should be easy if limited to `NumPy` arrays).  Therefore I added the `NO_CACHE` and `CLEAR_CACHE` keywords to the resulting function, which do what their names suggest.

After writing and using this function, I understand there is more than one good reason for `functools.lru_cache` to work only for functions with hashable input arguments.  Anyone needing a caching function that works with mutable arguments needs to be very careful.