# python flask: how to refresh global variable

Tags: python, flask

In a flask application I read a list of json values from a DB and keep it in memory for all views:

```
__init__.py
...
items = <load some stuff from remote API RESTDB>
...
```

In my views I import this variable:

```
someview.py
from project import items
...
```

My question is: How can I refresh this global var from time to time?

e.g. I want to refresh it when the application in a view writes to the RESTDB (thus changing the list of items).

Comment: Why not have a function you call everytime you write to the RESTDB?

Comment: Turn it into a function and memoize it? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674327/102315 (Also has a cache_clear() function to 'refresh' it.)

Comment: I am afraid I cannot follow...