# Python mixin/decorator/__metaclass__ for base class enhancement

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming, multiple-inheritance, python-decorators

I am implementing a content-aware caching system for a Django REST API. I would like to develop a component which can be added to existing views that would modify the behavior of the base class by checking the cache and falling back to the base class behavior on a miss.

basically, I have something like this:

```
class Base:
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       ....
       return Response

class AnotherBase:
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       .... 
       return Response

class Derived(Base):
    pass

class OtherDerived(AnotherBase):
    pass
```

and my initial thought was to do something along the lines of

```
class Cacheable:
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       cache_key = self.get_cache_key(request)
       base_get = #.... and this is the problem
       return cache.get(cache_key, base_get(request, *args, **kwargs))

    def get_cache_key(self, request):
       # .... do stuff

class Derived(Cacheable, Base):
    pass

class AnotherDerived(Cacheable, AnotherBase):
    pass
```

So clearly this doesn't work, as I don't know how, or if it's possible, or if it's advisable to access the sibling superclass(es) from a mixin.

My goal is an implementation that allows me to add caching behavior to existing views without touching the internals of the existing classes. 
Given a view class, `C`, s.t. `C.get(request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response`, is there a function, `F`, s.t. `F(C).get(...` does the cache check before falling back to `C.get`? And in this quasi-formal notation, we'll say that adding a mixin to the leftmost parent class in the class definition counts as a function.

Is it more appropriate to use method decorators? or how would a class decorator work?

And then I've seen references to `__metaclass__` in researching this, but I'm not clear on what that approach looks like.

This is Python 3.6

Comment: I'd argue that part of the problem is also `cache.get(cache_key, base_get(request, *args, **kwargs))`. You're needlessly computing the base get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a decorator and some `Django`-specific libraries.

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.core.cache import cache

def cached_get(cache_key_func=None):
    """
    Decorator to be applied via django.utils.decorators.method_decorator
    Implements content-aware cache fetching by decorating the "get" method
    on a django View
    :param cache_key_func: a function of fn(request, *args, **kwargs) --> String
    which determines the cache key for the request
    """
    def decorator(func):
        def cached_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            assert cache_key_func is not None, "cache_key_function is required"
            key = cache_key_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            result = cache.get(key)
            if result is None:
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return Response(result)
        return cached_func
    return decorator

@method_decorator(cached_get(cache_key_func=get_cache_key), name="get")
class SomeView(BaseView):
    ...

def get_cache_key(request):
    # do arbitrary processing on request, the following is the naïve melody
    key =  urllib.urlencode(request.query_params)
    return key
```

So the solution is to use Django's built-in `method_decorator` which applies its first argument, a decorator, to the decorated class's method, named by the second argument, `name`, to `method_decorator`. I define a higher-order function, `cached_get`, which takes another function as its argument, and returns a curried function (closure, so called). By calling this, with the function `get_cache_key` (and not, mind you, *invoking* that function) I have a decorator that will be applied to the 'get' method on `SomeView`.

The decorator itself is a straightforward Python decorator -- in this application, it is `cached_func` and the original, undecorated `get` method is `func`. Thus, `cached_func` replaces `SomeView.get`, so when `SomeView.get` is called, it first checks the cache, but falls back to the undecorated method on a miss.

I'm hopeful this approach provides a balance of generic applicability with content-aware key derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
def Base:

    def _get_data(self):
        # get the data eg from database
        return self._get_data_native()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(self._get_data())

def Cacheable(Base):

    def _get_data(self):
        # get from cache ...
        result = ...
        if result is None:
            # or from base ...
            result = ...

        return result

def Derived(Cacheable):

    def _get_data_native(self):
        # get the data eg from database
        ...
```

By inheriting from Cacheable, you include the caching here, because `_get_data` is overwritten there.

For this problem, you don't need metaclasses or decorators, if you want to just add caching at one place.

Of course, a decorator could be used for including caching in an even more generic way.

See for example this answer: [Is there a decorator to simply cache function return values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/815110/122012)

Comment: i'll elaborate in comments, but the example code you provide doesn't address my designs

Comment: not all the views inherit from the same base class, but can all be expected to have a public method, `get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Of course, they do: all inherit from object. I just wanted to provide an example how it could be done, not give you a complete solution. The complete solution must be defined by you in the context of your complete program.

Also: You don't need to have the same base class. Just define the right methods which you can overwrite. If all this does not fit your problem, you might have a look on the decorator solutions (I provided a link above). I don't think that you will need a metaclass for this kind of issue.

Comment: I understand how to do this with simple inheritance. What I am looking for is a technique that does not require changing the internals of the existing classes. This method would require refactoring all the existing views.

Comment: It is not possible to add new functionality without changing the classes in all cases. You can have a look on the decorator technique. If it works, you are lucky. If not, you will probably have to do some refactoring. It belongs to architecture foresight to construct your classes in a way, that additional functionality can easily be added. There is no "silver bullet" that magically adds things unconditionally to your design. That is the reason, why architecture and class design is something that needs much foresight and experience.

Answer (score -2):

My two cents:

1. You're walking into obscure territory here. Get familiar with all the related concepts, try a few, then decide.
2. [Here](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/) is a good tutorial about metaclasses.
3. [Here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) there's one about decorators.
4. I'm in no way affiliated to that site.

Comment: This is a nice comment, but I'd argue that as an answer it's link only. Your only real content is "play with it".

Comment: indeed, I am familiar with all the concepts, I am currently playing with the options. I came here because other people are likely to have insights, and because describing the problem so that other people can understand is the most effective strategy towards developing my own understanding.