# How to optimize these loops?

Tags: python, numpy

I am newbie at python, but still want to do things the easiest way.

Below I am posting my code, if some1 could look into it and figure out what is going wrong here, would be much of a help.

**Problem:** I have to solve nonlinear system of equations, which my code does on a given example. But when it comes to solving my own exercise it does not converge, meaning that `X(i-1)/x(1)` -> `1` is not fulfilled.

Other thing is that, it literally stops calculation on 5th iteration, but I haven't specified anything about 5th iteration, when first 3 iterations goes smoothly. I think it stores to much memory of some sort...but it is just my guess.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Needed variables and constants
n = 2
a1 = 0.04
a2 = 0.04
As1 = 19.64 * 10**(-4)
As2 = 12.64 * 10**(-4)
e0 = 0.07
b = 0.3
h = 0.5
Ned = 1990 * 10**3
fcd = 7.2 * 10**6
Ecm = 27 * 10**9
Es = 200 * 10**9
d = h - a1
e = (h/2) + e0
Eps2 = 0.002
Eps35 = 0.0035
d_x0 = 5 * 10**(-3)
d_r0 = 5 * 10**(-5)
fyd = 650 * 10**6

#Calculations
def x(i):
    if i == 1:
        return h
    return x(i - 1) + d_x(i-1)


def r(i):
    if i == 1:
        return (Ned * e) / ((Ecm * b * (h ** 3)) / 12)
    return r(i - 1) + d_r(i-1)


def d_x(i):
    A = np.array([[f1_x(i), f1_r(i)], [f2_x(i), f2_r(i)]])
    B = np.array([-f1(i), -f2(i)])
    C = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
    return C[0]


def d_r(i):
    A = np.array([[f1_x(i), f1_r(i)], [f2_x(i), f2_r(i)]])
    B = np.array([-f1(i), -f2(i)])
    C = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
    return C[1]


def Nb(i):
    return (b * fcd / r(i)) * (r(i) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (r(i) * (x(i) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1))


def Mb(i):
     return (b * fcd / (r(i) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - r(i) * (x(i) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * (r(i) * (x(i) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + (r(i) ** 2) * h * (x(i) - h / 2))


def Ns1(i):
    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - d) * As1


def Ns2(i):

    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - a2) * As2


def Ms1(i):
    return Es * r(i) * ((x(i) - d) ** 2) * As1

def Ms2(i):
    return Es * r(i) * ((x(i) - a2) ** 2) * As2


def f1(i):
    return Nb(i) + Ns1(i) + Ns2(i) - Ned


def f2(i):
    return Mb(i) + Ms1(i) + Ms2(i) - (Ned * (x(i) - (h / 2) + e0))


# Derivatives of all the required elements

def Ns1_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As1


def Ns1_r(i):
    return Es * As1 * (x(i) - d)


def Ns2_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As2


def Ns2_r(i):
    return Es * As2 * (x(i) - a2)


def Ms1_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As1 * 2 * (x(i) - d)


def Ms1_r(i):
    return Es * As1 * (x(i) - d) ** 2


def Ms2_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As2 * 2 * (x(i) - a2)


def Ms2_r(i):
    return Es * As2 * (x(i) - a2) ** 2


def Nb_x(i):
    return (((b * fcd / r(i)) * (r(i) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (r(i) * ((x(i) + d_x0) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1))) -((b * fcd / r(i)) * (r(i) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (r(i) * ((x(i) - d_x0) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1)))) / (2 * d_x0)


def Nb_r(i):
    return (((b * fcd / (r(i) + d_r0)) * ((r(i) + d_r0) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - ((r(i) + d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1))) -((b * fcd / (r(i) - d_r0)) * ((r(i) - d_r0) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - ((r(i) - d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1)))) / (2 * d_r0)


def Mb_x(i):
    return ((b * fcd / (r(i) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - r(i) * ((x(i) + d_x0) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * (r(i) * ((x(i) + d_x0) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + (r(i) ** 2) * h * ((x(i) + d_x0) - h / 2)) -(b * fcd / (r(i) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - r(i) * ((x(i) - d_x0) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * (r(i) * ((x(i) - d_x0) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + (r(i) ** 2) * h * ((x(i) - d_x0) - h / 2))) / (2 * d_x0)


def Mb_r(i):
    return ((b * fcd / ((r(i) + d_r0) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - (r(i) + d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * ((r(i) + d_r0) * (x(i) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + ((r(i) + d_r0) ** 2) * h * (x(i) - h / 2)) -(b * fcd / ((r(i) - d_r0) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - (r(i) - d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * ((r(i) - d_r0) * (x(i) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + ((r(i) - d_r0) ** 2) * h * (x(i) - h / 2))) / (2 * d_r0)


def f1_x(i):
    return Nb_x(i) + Ns1_x(i) + Ns2_x(i)


def f1_r(i):
    return Nb_r(i) + Ns1_r(i) + Ns2_r(i)


def f2_x(i):
    return Mb_x(i) + Ms1_x(i) + Ms2_x(i) - Ned


def f2_r(i):
    return Mb_r(i) + Ms1_r(i) + Ms2_r(i)


# Results of iterations

def Eps_C2(i):
    return x(i) * r(i)


def Eps_C1(i):
    return (x(i) - h) * r(i)


def Sig_S1(i):
    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - d)


def Sig_S2(i):
    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - a2)

for i in range(1,10):
    print('Iteration', i)
    print(Mb(i))
    print(Mb_r(i))
    print(d_r(i))
```

Comment: Why are you defining all your functions inside the loop?

Comment: Whatever the heck is going on in those 6 pages of formulas, you need to find a clearer way to express it. You'll take ages to notice or hunt down any typos you made in there, and it's hard to understand the meaning or structure to what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: For starters, almost all of your `if i==1` branches do the exact same thing as the other code path, just with the value of `1` hardcoded. Those branches are pointless. You could cut out almost half this code by removing those branches.

Comment: Other note, that it is not a memory consumption problem, my first guess, that it can be some exponentially growing calculation set.

Comment: Clearing those if's, and taking all of the code from loop did no good. Ofc code looks bit better, but still it gets stuck at 5th iteration.

Comment: The problem is, that the issue can be with the algorithm or/and it's parameter, or/and it can't converge to the value which the code could exit the algorithm after the 4th iteration or/and some code typo. The algorithm itself is too extensive to follow, you first have to insert some checkpoint in it, to know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

at a guess you're wasting a **lot** of time reevaluating the same, constant, expressions.  some of those calls look recursive and you're just wasting a lot of computational effort.  Python isn't the best language if you want to write code in your style — that might be how I'd think about it mathematically, but it's a terrible way for a computer to go about calculating it

as a hack, you could try putting a cache around each function, e.g:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def x(i):
    if i == 1:
        return h
    return x(i - 1) + d_x(i-1)
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674327/1358308)

if that works I'd recommend rewriting your code to save calculated values as it goes along.  for example, something like:

```
n = 10
x = np.zeros(n)
x[0] = h

for i in range(1, n):
  x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

t.y. for all comments.

As being a newbie, I am sorry again for posting such stuff.

All the good ideas come in a morning.

Problem was that, the code ran even w/o FOR loop. The thing is that every time code reached to the last called iteration.

Solution: I made global variable of newly calculated values after i calculation, and appended it to new global empty list. Then in second iteration it took values out of global variable, meaning it does not need to calculate all the stuff once again.

P.S If some1 wants to calculate a bit of engineering for nonlinear reinforced concrete, just change the given global variables.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#Needed variables and constants
n = 2   #Degree of nonlinearity(natural number ex.2,3,4 etc.)
a1 = 0.02   #Concrete cover of tensile reinf.[m]
a2 = 0.02   #Concrete cover of compressive reinf.[m]
As1 = 20 * 10**(-4)     #Area of tensile reinf.[m**2]
As2 = 20 * 10**(-4)     #Area of compressive reinf.[m**2]
e0 = 0.04       #Initial excetricity in [m]
b = 0.3         #Width of the columns cross-section.[m]
h = 0.3         #Height of the columns cross-section.[m]
Ned = 2600 * 10**3      #Axial Load.[N]
fcd = 8 * 10**6         #Concrete strength.[Pa]
Ecm = 27.6 * 10**9      #Concrete modulus of elasticity.[Pa]
Es = 200 * 10**9        #Steel modulus of elasticity. [Pa]
d = h - a1              #Effective height of tensile reinf. [m]
e = (h/2) + e0          #Excentricity of Ned[m]
Eps2 = 0.002            #Deformaton when stresses in concrete reaches fcd.
Eps35 = 0.0035          #Limit deformation for concrete.
d_x0 = 5 * 10**(-3)     #Increment for x. Needed when calculating derivatives of Mb and Nb.
d_r0 = 5 * 10**(-5)     #Increment fr r. Needed when calculating derivatives of Mb and Nb.
fyd = 600 * 10**6       #Yield stress for steel.[Pa]
d_x_n = []
d_r_n = []

#Calculation of nonlinear reinforced concrete.
#This code calculates 2 unknonws with system made out of 2 equations.
#Unknownws are physicaly connected in nonlinear dependecies.
#Solving this nonlinear system of equations is done by making linear iterative calculation, based on Taylor series.
#Program stops, when 2 adjacent iterations give same values.(at least 0.9999 accuracy)


def x(i):
    if i == 1:
        return h
    x_n = x(i-1) + d_x(i-1)
    return x_n

def r(i):
    if i == 1:
        return (Ned * e) / ((Ecm * b * (h ** 3)) / 12)
    r_n = r(i-1) + d_r(i-1)
    return r_n

def d_r(i):
    return d_r_n[i-1]

def d_x(i):
    return d_x_n[i-1]

def A(i):
    return np.array([[f1_x(i), f1_r(i)], [f2_x(i), f2_r(i)]])

def B(i):
    return np.array([-f1(i), -f2(i)])

def C(i):
    return np.linalg.solve(A(i), B(i))


def Nb(i):
    return (b * fcd / r(i)) * (r(i) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (r(i) * (x(i) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1))


def Mb(i):
     return (b * fcd / (r(i) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - r(i) * (x(i) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * (r(i) * (x(i) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + (r(i) ** 2) * h * (x(i) - (h / 2)))


def Ns1(i):
    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - d) * As1


def Ns2(i):

    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - a2) * As2


def Ms1(i):
    return Es * r(i) * ((x(i) - d) ** 2) * As1

def Ms2(i):
    return Es * r(i) * ((x(i) - a2) ** 2) * As2


def f1(i):
    return Nb(i) + Ns1(i) + Ns2(i) - Ned


def f2(i):
    return Mb(i) + Ms1(i) + Ms2(i) - (Ned * (x(i) - (h / 2) + e0))


# Derivatives of all the required elements

def Ns1_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As1


def Ns1_r(i):
    return Es * As1 * (x(i) - d)


def Ns2_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As2


def Ns2_r(i):
    return Es * As2 * (x(i) - a2)


def Ms1_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As1 * 2 * (x(i) - d)


def Ms1_r(i):
    return Es * As1 * (x(i) - d) ** 2


def Ms2_x(i):
    return Es * r(i) * As2 * 2 * (x(i) - a2)


def Ms2_r(i):
    return Es * As2 * (x(i) - a2) ** 2


def Nb_x(i):
    return (((b * fcd / r(i)) * (r(i) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (r(i) * ((x(i) + d_x0) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1))) -((b * fcd / r(i)) * (r(i) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - (r(i) * ((x(i) - d_x0) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1)))) / (2 * d_x0)


def Nb_r(i):
    return (((b * fcd / (r(i) + d_r0)) * ((r(i) + d_r0) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - ((r(i) + d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1))) -((b * fcd / (r(i) - d_r0)) * ((r(i) - d_r0) * h - (Eps2 / (n + 1)) * (1 - ((r(i) - d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) / Eps2) ** (n + 1)))) / (2 * d_r0)


def Mb_x(i):
    return (((b * fcd / (r(i) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - r(i) * ((x(i)+d_x0) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * (r(i) * ((x(i)+d_x0) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + (r(i) ** 2) * h * ((x(i)+d_x0) - (h / 2))))-((b * fcd / (r(i) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - r(i) * ((x(i)-d_x0) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * (r(i) * ((x(i)-d_x0) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + (r(i) ** 2) * h * ((x(i)-d_x0) - (h / 2))))) / (2 * d_x0 )


def Mb_r(i):
    return (((b * fcd / ((r(i)+d_r0) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - (r(i)+d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * ((r(i)+d_r0) * (x(i) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + ((r(i)+d_r0) ** 2) * h * (x(i) - (h / 2))))-((b * fcd / ((r(i)+d_r0) ** 2)) * (-(((Eps2 - (r(i)+d_r0) * (x(i) - h)) ** (n + 1)) * ((r(i)+d_r0) * (x(i) - h) * (n + 1) + Eps2) / ((n + 2) * (n + 1) * (Eps2 ** n))) + ((r(i)+d_r0) ** 2) * h * (x(i) - (h / 2))))) / (2 * d_r0)


def f1_x(i):
    return Nb_x(i) + Ns1_x(i) + Ns2_x(i)


def f1_r(i):
    return Nb_r(i) + Ns1_r(i) + Ns2_r(i)


def f2_x(i):
    return Mb_x(i) + Ms1_x(i) + Ms2_x(i) - Ned


def f2_r(i):
    return Mb_r(i) + Ms1_r(i) + Ms2_r(i)


# Results of iterations

def Eps_C2(i):
    return x(i) * r(i)


def Eps_C1(i):
    return (x(i) - h) * r(i)


def Sig_S1(i):
    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - d)


def Sig_S2(i):
    return Es * r(i) * (x(i) - a2)

for i in range(1,20):
    d_x_n.append((C(i)[0]))
    d_r_n.append((C(i)[1]))
    print('Iteration', i)
    print(x(i))
    if round(x(i)/x(i+1), 4) == 1 and round(r(i)/r(i+1), 4) == 1:
        print('Ratio between two iterations ', round(x(i)/x(i+1), 4) )
        print('Convergence reached in ', i, 'Iterations')
        break
    else:
        print('Convergence was not reached in ', i, 'Iterations, calculation aborts')


print('Stress in tensile reinforcement,', Sig_S1(i))
print('Stress in compressive reinforcement,', Sig_S2(i))
print('Deformations in C1', Eps_C1(i))
print('Deformations in C2', Eps_C2(i))
```