# Duplicate len(array) operations in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

If I have the following (not very useful) recursive function

```
def recursion(array, index=5):
  # Base case
  if index == len(array) - 1:
    return 0
  
  return recursion(array, index+1)
```

how does python handle `len(array)` in this case given that the array remains constant throughout the recursion? I.e. is there any behind the scenes caching?

Comment: No, there isn't any special treatment for constant arguments in a recursive call.

Comment: `index` is increasing.

Comment: `array` is constant, but `index` is changing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no caching like this in python. That is, len(array) will always be evaluated, it doesn't save the return value once it knows the result for a given set of input parameters.

However, this *can* be achieved with decorators. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values) thread, or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnKxKFXB4NQ) video.