"Preprocessing" a Python function, to avoid excess evaluation of conditional logic
I am writing some Python code that includes functions with two sets of parameters. The first set of parameters will be different every single time the function is called. The second set of parameters will be the same for large groups of function calls (e.g., these change every 10000s of evaluations of the function). I am hoping to write this function in such a way that the conditional logic is run only once whenever the values of the second set of parameters change. I have included some code that I think might work, but after some testing with the time module, the improvement seems very small. Is this code actually doing what I am describing? And if not, is there some way to do this in Python?
def preprocessor(parameter_array):
    # example parameters
    condition = parameter_array[0]
    index = parameter_array[1]

    def f(x_array):
        result = 0
        if (condition):
            result += x_array[index] ** 2
        else:
            result += x_array[index] - 5
        # ...
        return result

    return f

# define some test parameters
test_parameters = [True, 1]

# run the function 100000 times with these parameters
function = preprocessor(test_parameters)

sum = 0
for i in range(100000):
    sum += function([i, i])

print(sum)

My hope is that, written in this way, the if statement is only evaluated whenever I call the preprocessor function. Thus, it speeds up the evaluation of the for loop, where only the x values change. This took around 0.024 seconds to run, while a control took around 0.028 seconds to run. I have also included the code I used for the control below (everything is without the time module for readability).
def f(x_array, parameter_array):
    # example parameters
    condition = parameter_array[0]
    index = parameter_array[1]

    result = 0
    if (condition):
        result += x_array[index] ** 2
    else:
        result += x_array[index] - 5
    # ...
    return result

# define some test parameters
test_parameters = [True, 1]

# run the function 100000 times without using the preprocessed function
sum = 0
for i in range(100000):
    sum += f([i, i], test_parameters)

print(sum)


The if (condition): is inside the function f being returned by preprocessor(), so it's evaluated on every single call to the function - I don't understand how you thought this would speed anything up.  You could get rid of the conditional by having preprocessor() return one of two implementations of f, each one having a different calculation of result - but the potential speed gain would be fairly small.

Have you read up on Python decorators?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values can be useful

@jasonharper I see. That is what I was afraid of. The problem of returning one of two implementations is that the code I gave is just a toy example to explain the problem. In my actual use case I have 100s of parameters, so the possible permutations of parameters grows too large for this to be practical. Thank you for your help.

Answer:
Yes, it's doing what you think it's doing. An easy way to tell is just to add some print statements.
def initialize(initialState):
    state = initialState
    print(f"I am executed on initialization: {state}")
    def f(increment): 
        nonlocal state
        print(f"I am incrementing {state} by {increment}")
        state = state + increment

    return f

fun = initialize(10)
fun(5)
fun(20)

output
I am executed on initialization: 10
I am incrementing 10 by 5
I am incrementing 15 by 20

Aside:
Your example may just be too reductive, but the logic you're extracting is extremely simple. You're not going to get that much of speed up. I'm not sure if there's extra code between the conditional and the return, but declaring the return value and then incrementing it based on the condition's result is unnecessary.
Here, I've compared your approach, with two different simplifications and both achieve a speedup. Python is truly a strange language. Every compiled language I know of is able to eliminate branching instructions when using a ternary. I would expect the ternary approach to be the fastest.
import timeit

def approach1(): 
    def preprocessor (parameter_array):
        condition = parameter_array[0]
        index = parameter_array[1]
        return lambda x_array: x_array[index] ** 2 if condition else x_array[index] - 5
    test_parameters = [True, 1]
    function = preprocessor(test_parameters)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        sum += function([i, i])
    
def approach2():
    def preprocessor (parameter_array):
        condition = parameter_array[0]
        index = parameter_array[1]
        def f (x_array):
            result = 0
            if (condition):
                result += x_array[index] ** 2
            else:
                result += x_array[index] - 5
            return result
        return f
    
    test_parameters = [True, 1]
    function = preprocessor(test_parameters)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        sum += function([i, i])

def approach3():
    def preprocessor (parameter_array):
        condition = parameter_array[0]
        index = parameter_array[1]
        def f (x_array):
            if (condition):
                return x_array[index] ** 2
            return x_array[index] - 5
        return f
    test_parameters = [True, 1]
    function = preprocessor(test_parameters)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        sum += function([i, i])

n = 100
print(timeit.timeit(approach1, number=n))
print(timeit.timeit(approach2, number=n))
print(timeit.timeit(approach3, number=n))

output
0.8117037120027817
0.9467067930017947
0.8014805819984758

P.S.
While these types of optimizations can be fun and help you learn about performance characteristics of the language, your time is much better spent on optimizing things like the algorithms you're using. If you really need performance, Python is not the language for you.

Thank you for your thorough response. I think I was not clear enough in my original question. But yes, I do have a lot more code between the conditional and the return like you said. The example I gave was just to illustrate my problem.

Performance issues a very, very specific. It's hard to give any recommendations when I don't know what it's doing. I generally follow 2 approaches:

caching / memoization  -- what you're trying to do
reduction

#2 is reducing not only instructions to the CPU but also memory allocations. See if you're unnecessarily allocating memory in loops.

Also, calling a function does have some overhead. If you're in a hot loop like at the bottom of the example, it may be best to just do that summation inside the function your calling.

That is fair. I can give some more context. I am trying to do a curve_fit of some data to a system of ODEs that depend on some set of parameters. This involves using an ODE solver to solve the system for each set of parameters the curve fitting algorithm tries. This is what creates the need to call a function (to get the derivatives) 1000s of times for varying x values, but the with the same parameters. Unfortunately, the equation's dependence on some of the parameters is not as simple as setting a variable, and involves if statements etc.

I'm not familiar. Is this something that's iterative? Meaning it depends on the previous state to calculate the current state? Or is it something done on a matrix?

It is iterative in the sense that the x_array given as input would depend on the values of all the previous function calls.

I was going to recommend something like Pandas/Numpy or Polars but I don't think they would help in that case.
You could try out https://numba.pydata.org/ and see if it helps at all, but they really want Numpy arrays.
One place you could see an improvement (if your parameter list is homogeneous) is replace the list with an array: https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html.
Lists need to be traversed whereas arrays can be directly indexed into.
